# EF Core vs Aggregate Root - Is there a way to prevent persisting changes to child entities?

Tags: entity-framework-core, domain-driven-design, encapsulation

I'll use the common example of an `Order` aggregate root which has a collection of `LineItems`.

Because all changes need to go through the aggregate root, I add a `IReadOnlyList<LineItem> LineItems` navigation property to the `Order`, backed by a `private readonly List<LineItem> lineItems` field. So now we can't just do `order.LineItems.Add()`, but instead we have to use an appropriate `AddLineItem` method on the aggregate root to add the line item.

But, in order to be able to use the `AddLineItem` on an `Order` entity fetched from the database using EF Core, I need to use `Include(o => o.LineItems)` in my query, otherwise `LineItems` would be `null`, and I'd get an exception when trying to add to it. So what's stopping me from getting a LineItem from the read-only list and doing changes on it, and then persisting them using `DbContext.SaveChanges()`?

Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make your setters internal on `LineItem`.  Then the only entities that can change them are those in the same assembly, e.g. the `Order`.

All requests to change properties of the LineItem should be routed through the Order, which can then enforce invariants and use internal setters to update the LineItem (or even use internal methods on the LineItem, which takes care of updating properties with private setters).